# Python requests.Session() not updating all cookies?

Tags: python-3.x, cookies, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape data from a website and seem to have an issue getting/setting cookies from the website when I use requests.session

See code bellow

```
import pickle
import re
import requests

def save_cookies(requests_cookiejar, filename):
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(requests_cookiejar, f)


def load_cookies(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        return pickle.load(f)


s = requests.Session()
r = s.get("http://192.168.1.16/phpmyadmin/", cookies=load_cookies("Cookie.txt"))
r = s.get("http://192.168.1.16/phpmyadmin/")
save_cookies(r.cookies, "Cookie.txt")
```

See
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fQRR.jpg) with the 2 GET requests, I don't understand why the cookies like: pmaCookieVer, pma_lang.. etc are getting 'lost'.

PS: I will use a different website for scraping data, my local one is just for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `requests.Session` instance that is assigned to `s` to manage your requests, the individual `Response` instances returned by `s.get` will not contain the cookies, but the `requests.Session` instance will.  Here is a demonstration:

```py
>>> import requests
>>> s = requests.Session()
>>> r1 = s.get('http://httpbin.org/cookies/set/sessioncookie/123456789')
>>> len(r1.cookies)
0
>>> len(s.cookies)
1
>>> print(s.cookies['sessioncookie'])
123456789
>>> r2 = s.get('http://httpbin.org/cookies/set/anothercookie/123456789')
>>> len(r2.cookies)
0
>>> len(s.cookies)
2
```

You can see that the cookies are in fact being accumulated at the cookie jar on the session rather than on the request object being returned (e.g. instead of `r.cookies`, use `s.cookies` as the argument for saving).  To wrap this up, simulate saving and loading of cookies with a different session object:

```py
>>> save_cookies(s.cookies, 'cookies.txt')
>>> new_session = requests.Session()
>>> new_session.cookies = load_cookies('cookies.txt')
>>> r3 = new_session.get("http://httpbin.org/cookies")
>>> r3.json()
{'cookies': {'anothercookie': '123456789', 'sessioncookie': '123456789'}}
```